# cshで長いコマンド列に短いエイリアスを設定したい

Tags: command-line, csh

pythonのanacondaで環境を切り替えるときに`source ~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-4.0.0/bin/activate 環境名`を毎回フルパスで入力するのが面倒なのでどうにかして短いエイリアスのようなものにしたいのですが、方法がわかりません。cshを使っているので関数も定義できないので困っています。

何か良い方法などありませんか。

Answer (score 1):

cshにも`alias`はあるようなので`.cshrc`などで設定するとよいでしょう。
例えば

```
alias ll "ls -lFh --color=auto"
```

などとして置けば、`ll`というコマンドが出来ます。

```
ll ~/
```

のように引数を与えて使用する事も出来ます。

Comment: `Illegal variable name.`とでてできません。

Comment: そもそも、csh で `source ~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-4.0.0/bin/activate 環境名` が成功していますか？

Comment: 成功しません。上記エラーが出ます

Comment: でしたら、それにエイリアスを設定しても動かないのは同じ事です。`source ~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-4.0.0/bin/activate`がcshでは動かない、というのは別の問題なので切り分けて考えて下さい。

Comment: お手元の`bin/activate`は[これ](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/bin/activate)ですか？ だとすると"Only bash and zsh are supported"だそうです。cshで使うには別の手順が必要だと思うので、別の質問を立てた方がよいかと。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。